# Code after fetch call is seemingly not read

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm making a POST request to a local Express server with a JSON as its body and I'm doing this inside an async function:

```
    async function sendSigninForm(login_form) {
    const settings = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(login_form)
    };

    try {
        await fetch(`http://localhost:9000/signin`, settings)

    } catch (e) {
        return e;
    }        
}
```

I tried accessing fetch's response in various ways, like

```
const fetchResponse = await fetch(`http://localhost:9000/signin`, settings);
const data = await fetchResponse.json();
```

or

```
const fetchResponse = await fetch(`http://localhost:9000/signin`, settings)
    .then((value) => console.log(value));
```

but neither of these work, and I can't even print anything.

```
const fetchResponse = await fetch(`http://localhost:9000/signin`, settings)
    .then(console.log("hello"));
```

This works, but of course it won't let me print fetch's response so it's useless to me. Also, the server is apparently working correctly as it gets the form as required and queries the database correctly.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console? Instead of returning `e` you might want to log it to the console to troubleshoot. Also, it would be helpful for us to see where you call `sendSigninForm`

Comment: @Nick it seems like it hangs unless status codes are sent, which is how I fixed this!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I forgot to send status codes server-side, and apparently that's the reason it hanged, although everything seemed to be fine and the queries were actually executed.